# Include 'tomcat manager' webapp in tomee maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, apache-tomee

I would like to use the tomee maven plugin to provision my tomee server. As I'm using Netbeans for develoment (which in turn relies on the tomcat manager app to be installed) I would like to include the manager app into the generated tomee installation when I call `mvn tomee:build`

Is there a way to refer to the tomcat manager app somehow (inside the webapps tag of the pom?) so that it is installed inside the webapps folder?

This is my tomee plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tomee.version}</version>
    <configuration>     
        <tomeeVersion>${tomee.version}</tomeeVersion>
        <tomeeClassifier>plume</tomeeClassifier>
        <args></args>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debugPort>5005</debugPort>
        <config>${project.basedir}/tomee/conf</config>
        <libs>       
        </libs>
        <webapps>
        <!-- Is there something I could enter here to have the (correct version of) tomcat manager webapp installed ? -->
        </webapps>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The default TomEE distribution package already exists `manager` under the `webapps` directory.

Comment: Thats correct, however I want to use the tomee-maven-plugin to create my distribution. In this case, the manager is missing, and I need to copy it manually into the webapps directory. Of coures on each clean-build I need to repeat this, which is very teadious.

Comment: Does your `my distribution` mean that you are building your own TomEE distribution? Or your own WebApp distribution?

Comment: I'm not building my own distribution, I basically want the plugin to install the Tomee distribution of choice. If I download the distribution manually, it contains the manager webapp. However if I let it be installed by the tomee-plugin, the manager webapp is not bundled.

Answer (score 0):

For the records:
I found the following 'solution':

Add "removeDefaultWebapps = false" to tomee maven plugin's configuration section like so:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomee.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${tomee.version}</version>
<configuration>     
<tomeeVersion>${tomee.version}</tomeeVersion>
<tomeeClassifier>plume</tomeeClassifier>
<!-- this will 'install' (aka not remove) the default webapps that come with tomee -->
<removeDefaultWebapps>false</removeDefaultWebapps>
<args></args>
<debug>true</debug>
<debugPort>5005</debugPort>
<config>${project.basedir}/tomee/conf</config>
<libs> ...  </libs>
<webapps> ... </webapps>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```